# how to change install component css only in Special component in nextjs

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js

I have been working with nextjs.I want to change the react-slick CSS style in a special component but in nextjs v10 I can only apply this change in global.css.
this changes the react-slick style in all pages and components.
for example:

```
ul.slick-dots {
  text-align: left !important;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
ul.slick-dots li {
  width:15px;
  height: 15px;
  margin: 0;
}
.slick-dots li button{
  width:15px;
  height: 15px;
}
.slick-dots li button:before{
  width:15px;
  height: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}
.slick-dots li.slick-active button:before{
  color: #ca2026;
}
.progress-edit {
  margin-top: 40px;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  direction: rtl;
}
.bar-edit {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
```

when I import this code `import styles from "./Slider.module.css";` in slider.js, nothing change, and when I import `'styles/Slider.css'` in _app.js styles changed.

how can apply this style only slider.js component?

Comment: did you try `import 'styles/Slider.css'` in `slider.js`

Comment: yes.but got an error 
`Global CSS cannot be imported from files other than your Custom <App>. Please move all global CSS imports to pages/_app.js. Or convert the import to Component-Level CSS (CSS Modules).`

Comment: ok....only solution is to use jsx like this `<div className="container">
      <h1>Next.js with Framer Motion</h1>
      <h4>data from getInitialProps: {message} </h4>
      <p>Let's explore different ways to animate Next.js pages</p>
      <style jsx>{`
        .container {
          margin: 50px;
        }
        p {
          color: red;
        }
        h4 {
          color: orange;
        }
      `}</style>
    </div>`

Comment: thanks. that's not possible because I use only `<Slider {...settings}>{children}</Slider>` in component and I decide to change classes that `Slider` get internal. I do not have access to `Slider` component classes directly.

Comment: try this `<Slider {...settings}>
<>
{children}
 <style>
        {`
    h1{
      color:blue
    }
  `}
      </style>
</>
</Slider>`

Comment: if add `<></>` slider don't work correctly